# how to change integer to 2 bytes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an algorithm problem I need to solve. But I do not really understand the question after spending a day to grasp it.

> PROBLEM: For this task, you need to write a small program including a
>   pair of functions that can
>
> convert an integer into a special text encoding The Encoding Function
>
> This function needs to accept a signed integer in the 14-bit range
>   [-8192..+8191] and return a 4 character string.
>
> The encoding process is as follows:
>
> 1.Add 8192 to the raw value, so its range is translated to [0..16383]
>   2.Pack that value into two bytes such that the most significant bit of each is cleared
>
> Unencoded intermediate value (as a 16-bit integer):
>
> 00HHHHHH HLLLLLLL
>
> Encoded value:
>
> 0HHHHHHH 0LLLLLLL
>
> 1 of 3
>
> Format the two bytes as a single 4-character hexadecimal string and
>   return it. Sample values:
>
> Unencoded (decimal) | Intermediate (decimal) | Intermediate (hex) |
>   Encoded (hex)
>
> 0 | 8192 | 2000 | 4000
>
> -8192 | 0 | 0000 | 0000
>
> 8191 | 16383 | 3fff | 7F7F
>
> 2048 | 10240 | 2800 | 5000
>
> -4096 | 4096 | 1000 | 2000

The part '2.Pack that value into two bytes such that the most significant bit of each is cleared' is my obstacle now.

what should I do with this instruction?
Thank you so much in advance.

I tried to convert the number to 16bit by the code below. But I don't know what should do next.

```
let rawInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputValue").value);
let interDec= Number.parseInt(rawInput) + 8192
let interHex = interDec.toString(16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try - the `+('0b'+binString)` parse binary string to js number (the `toString`, `slice` and `padStart` are standard well documented js functions)

```js
function convert(num) {
  let b = (num+8192).toString(2).padStart(14,'0');
  let L = ( +('0b'+b.slice(7))   ).toString(16).padStart(2,'0');
  let H = ( +('0b'+b.slice(0,7)) ).toString(16).padStart(2,'0');
  return H+L;
}

console.log('    0 =>', convert(    0));
console.log('-8192 =>', convert(-8192));
console.log(' 8191 =>', convert( 8191));
console.log(' 2048 =>', convert( 2048));
console.log('-4096 =>', convert(-4096));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day! I would like to ask you one more thing. In this part ( +('0b'+b.slice(7))   ), what does the '+' before '0b' work? I could understand '0b'' represent the data is binary, and the + symbol alters the number, but I couldnt understand it.

Comment: @ShinCat this second `+` (after `'0b'`) is string concatenation, the `b.slice(7)` is string with bits e.g. "110101" so  `"0b"+b.slice(7))` gives string `"0b110101"` - and this string can be easyli cast as binary to js number by first `+` operator: `+("0b110101")`. If this helps don't forget do accept this answer by click on its left side on big gray 'check' button (you can also up-vote by click on gray upper triangle)

Comment: Are you sure this produces unique results for all values in the range? Looks to me like you're losing information by only using 14 bits, when there are 15 significant bits of information.

Comment: @JimMischel in OP question there is sentence: *This function needs to accept a signed integer in the 14-bit range [-8192..+8191]...* ( JS: `(8191+8192).toString(2)` => 11111111111111  - 14 bits) - so probably you are right - however solution meet OP requirements

Comment: ＠Kamil Kiełczewski 　Thank you for kind answer. let me clarify about first +. So The + is the way of handling the number as binary in Javascript. Am I correct?

Comment: The `+` is one (short) way of parsing strings to number (equivalent of e.g. [parseInt("10",2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/parseInt)), this operator also depend on context - with some strings it can be use to cast them to number - try in browser console: `+"10"`(dec), `+"0b10"`(binary), `+"0o10"` (oct), `+"0x10"` (hex), `"1"+"10"` (concatenate strings), `+"1"+ +"10"` (cast strings to num and add them)

Answer (score 2):

When you added 8192 to integer, you have value of kind (binary representation) `00HHHHHH HLLLLLLL`

1) You have to preserve right (`L`) bits - just separate them with bitwise AND using bitmask `0x7f` ((binary `00000000 01111111`))

2) Shift all value left, getting `0HHHHHHH LLLLLLL0`, now `H` bits stay at the final places

3) Separate `H` bits with bitwise AND using mask `0x7f00`  (binary `01111111 00000000`)

4) Combine low and high parts together with binary OR

Python example

```
v = 0x3fff
ev = (v & 0x7f) | ((v<<1) & 0x7f00)
print(hex(ev))

>>>0x7f7f
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I use Javascript, you gave me a great suggestion that bitwise and mask. I'll study it.

Comment: This loses information. If you add 8192 to 8191, you end up with 16383. In binary, that's `01111111 11111111`. Shifted left, that gives you `11111111 1111110`. If you then AND with `0x7f00`, you lose the high bit. Your method will lose information.

Comment: @Jim Mischel  You are not right -  `16383 = 0x3FFF = 00111111 11111111`

Comment: Best answer. Converting this to JS is pretty trivial. Replace `print(hex(ev))` with `console.log(ev.toString(16))` et viola. And add `const` to var declarations to avoid globals for best practice.